# Logging with Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, stackdriver

I have two questions regarding logging with apps script:

1/ I have two .gs files (in the same project). One (F1) is calling the other (F2) via `urlfetch` (POST request). The `Logger.log` works just fine in F1, but doesn't in F2 (maybe it works too, but I just can't retrieve the logs). Do you know if it's normal or where can I find the logs of F2 ?
(If you're wondering, it's made this way so we can call the same function multiple times in parallel).

2/ My scripts are linked to a Google Cloud project and so I've seen we can retrieve some logs via Stackdriver. What logs ? Because those with `Logger.log` don't seem to be visible from there.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Think of the different .gs files in a project as ways of organizing your functions.  The functions in each are available to each .gs file  so if F2 has a function `f2function(myVar) {//code}` in F1 you can call it with `f2function(sendVar);`  Logger.log  is reported i the same log for both .gs files.

Comment: The architecture is made this way to create different threads and so call the same function, multiple times, in parallel

Comment: In your situation, I would log your data to a spreadsheet.  I can't say for sure what the current situation is, but from personal experience, in the past, it seemed that in some situations, the logs from some functions did not print.  You can create your own, simple log system, and just append data to a spreadsheet.  I have a function name `ll`.  `function ll(a,b,c) {SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('name').appendRow(a,b,c)}`  My function is not that simple, but I'm just showing the basics.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your second question: Stackdriver Logging with Apps Script is a new feature, only accessible to G Suite Business customers that applied for [early access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging_early_access).
The following functions should work

```
console.log([data][,...])
console.info([data][,...])
console.warn([data][,...])
console.error([data][,...])
console.time([label])
```

Comment: Now it's available to projects that use a Google Clould standard project.