# How to measure execution time of query on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, cloud, google-cloud-platform

How to measure execution time of query on Google Cloud?

Earlier there was provision of Query Browser of Google. Which is now absolute and redirected to google cloud console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use Stackdriver Trace. You can search "Trace" in GCP console, and then it shows list of requests. Click on the requests you are interested and you can see execution timelines.

Appstats provides more details and customization, but definitely needs more work.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. Is there any way to trace query execution through Google Script?

Comment: what do you mean by Google Script?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Google script.

Comment: Google Apps Script is not part of the Google Cloud Platform and isn't connected to your Cloud Platform Project, so you won't be able to monitor it using the Stackdriver tools. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696033/logging-with-google-apps-script) this might soon change but is not generally available yet.